# Wpf Listbox doesn't bind to multiple items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

the Xaml looks like this:

```
<ListBox Name="lbEurInsuredType" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="0,2">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"></ColumnDefinition>
                                      <ColumnDefinition Width="30"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <!--     <ColumnDefinition Width="20"></ColumnDefinition>-->
                   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
                             <TextBox Text="{Binding Uw}"></TextBox>
                        <!--    <TextBox Text="{Binding Partner}"></TextBox>-->
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate></ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        </ListBox>
```

then in my code behind I have :

```
public DefaultSettings()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<EurItem> items = new List<EurItem>
            {
                new EurItem() { Title = "Couple", Uw = 190m, Partner = 170m },
                new EurItem() { Title = "Family", Uw = 180m, Partner = 160m } 
            };

            lbEurInsuredType.ItemsSource = items;

        }
```

What happens is that If I Only have the TextBlock in the xaml, then the title shows in the listbox, as soon as I start to introduce other members, then it displays the last item that has been bound and looses all the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unnecessary because you are already directly setting it in your code behind.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding}"
```

Also, you are not setting any `Grid.Column` definitions on your succeeding elements. So they are overlapping each other.

You might want something like this

```
<Grid Margin="0,2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="80"></ColumnDefinition>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="30"></ColumnDefinition>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="20"></ColumnDefinition>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
         <TextBox Text="{Binding Uw}" Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>
         <TextBox Text="{Binding Partner}" Grid.Column="2"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I have removed this, but it's made no difference

Comment: @bilpor I added more.

Comment: Can I ask another Quick question related to this........I now have the 3 items showing, but above the 2nd and 3rd item I want to give a header have you any idea how I can do that?

Comment: It's better if you create a new question so that other people that would have similar problems related to yours can easily relate. I'd be happy to answer you on that thread. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're placing several controls in a `Grid` with several columns. By default, each item you place inside a `Grid` is shown in the first row and first column.

Since you're not telling the controls otherwise, all your controls are being added to the first row and column, overlapping each other... So only the last control is shown.

You need to use `Grid.Column` to specify which column should each control be placed in.

```
<ListBox Name="lbEurInsuredType" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="0,2">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"></ColumnDefinition>
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
               <TextBox Text="{Binding Uw}" Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>
               <TextBox Text="{Binding Partner}" Grid.Column="2"></TextBox>
           </Grid>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```